# Best practice's to send an UIImage from one controller to another?

Tags: iphone, ios5

UIImage can be sent from one controller to another in the following 2 ways

First Method:(Where in secondViewController we define UIImage *image2; )
secondViewController.image2=firstController.imageView.image ;

Second Method (Where in secondViewController we define NSData *recievedData):

NSData *data= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,0.5);

secondViewController.recievedData=data;

My doubt is which is the most efficient way of sending the image with less memory consumed ?

Comment: secondViewController.image2=firstController.imageView.image with this code is only assigning a pointer, because so cpu comsuming is almost zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the UIImage directly. Encoding it as jpeg and then decoding it again is a waste of cpu cycles and memory.